# Can you use EOS Utility to Manual Focus whilst remote shooting movies?

Tags: canon, manual-focus, eos-utility

I have a 700D and want to use EOS Utility remote shooting to make videos. I want to avoid using Auto Focus as it is SO loud as it constantly focuses. I can't seem to find a way to manually focus through the utility using MF. Only option so far has been to focus the camera first on the actual camera, and then begin shooting. But as I am filming myself on camera it would be ideal to be able to focus manually through the utility itself.

Many thanks!

Comment: This appears to be video specific.  It would probably be a better fit on [Video Production](http://video.stackexchange.com).  A moderator should be able to move it for you.

Answer (score 3):

The EOS utility can only adjust the focus on your camera when the lens is set to `AF` (as it needs to use the motors in the lens to move the elements).

If your lens is set to `AF` you should be able to adjust the focus in EOS Utility using this area:

[image: image of EOS Utility Focus Control Panel]
*Note the arrow buttons in particular, these can be used for adjusting the focus remotely by eye*

However, as this will use the same motors that are generating noise, it may not be a solution for you.

To reduce focussing noise, your options would probably be to either continue manually focussing the lens, or buy a new lens that produces less noise when focussing. Canons lenses with STM in the name have motors that allow near-silent focusing when shooting video, so you may want to have a look at them in particular.

Example STM lens: [Canon EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS STM](http://www.canon.co.uk/For_Home/Product_Finder/Cameras/EF_Lenses/EF-S/EF-S_18-55mm_f_3.5-5.6_IS_STM/)

Comment: Those arrow buttons are unfortunate. A slider that lets you change focus as quickly or slowly as you like would be more like a real focus ring and much easier to control.

Comment: @WilliamShakespeare agreed, the buttons are not particularly easy to use.